# Printing Appended Comments

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365

We are running an Office 365 SharePoint Site and have a dataview page we are using to print multiple list items. The problem we are running into is when we include the comment field it only shows a View Entries link. Using the AppendOnlyHistory control, we keep getting errors pertaining to the ID (I think it is a problem with the control being repeated).